# Is there any way to tell NHibernate to exclude a specific table from a Schema Export?

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate's SchemaExport to create my database schema. I have 1 legacy ref table that cannot be recreated with the Schema Export because it is already in use with other apps that use the same DB. Is there any way to map this table but tell NHibernate to skip it when running the SchemaExport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature was recently added to the NHibernate trunk (see [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/nhibernate-development/browse_thread/thread/d500e30bae29ae48/cee532fb4622e992?lnk=gst&q=schemaexport) in the NHibernate development mailing list).  So if you are using the trunk, you can use the "schema-action" attribute to control the behavior of SchemaExport().

Answer (score 2):

Try using SchemaUpdate() instead? it should see the table already exists and not issue a CREATE statement